# Kotlin 1.0.0-rc-1036 problems with Annotation Processing

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I have an Android App using **Raizlabs DBFlow 2.2.1** and I updated my kotlin version to **1.0.0-rc-1036** but now when I try to run the app it gives me the following error:

https://gist.github.com/yiyocx/3cc9cf594121eba7ab0e

I tried doing a clean and run againt but this just works for the first launch, in the following launches I receive the same error as above. I think that error is due to a problem with Annotations, I'm using **kapt**.

These are my DBFlow dependencies in app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    kapt 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Compiler:2.2.1'
    compile "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1"
    compile "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1"
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Comment: it's not obvious that kapt is a problem in your case. try to revise your code, since first RC most (if not all) deprecated features became errors. also now kotlin is aware of @Nullable etc annotations.

Comment: run with `--info` parameter for gradle, or `--stacktrace` to see more details, then you will know more, and can share more here.

Comment: You are right, I updated the question adding more error details in a gist